# Change tracking using Kusto queries

Tags: kql, change-tracking

I have data in kusto table that gets updated with every deployment. I want to check what change was made in a particular deployment

| Column A | Column B | Modified at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | Value 1 | Dec 15 |
| Row 2 | Value 2 | Dec 15 |
| Row 3 | Value 6 | Dec 15 |
| Row 4 | Value 5 | Dec 15 |
| Row 1 | Value 1 | Dec 14 |
| Row 2 | Value 2 | Dec 14 |
| Row 3 | Value 6 | Dec 14 |
| Row 4 | Value 4 | Dec 14 |
| Row 1 | Value 1 | Dec 13 |
| Row 2 | Value 2 | Dec 13 |
| Row 3 | Value 3 | Dec 13 |
| Row 4 | Value 4 | Dec 13 |

Now if we need to track change by column A values in column B
Row 3 has a value change on Dec 14 load (From Value 3 to Value 6 )
Row 4 has a value change on Dec 15 load (From Value 4 to Value 5)

I want to extract data on each date as for what all has changed like to project only changed rows for a date ,and I can run this query daily to find the daily change tracking

| Column A | Column B | Modified at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 4 | Value 5 | Dec 15 |

| Column A | Column B | Modified at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 4 | Value 5 | Dec 15 |

Comment: Please avoid - **(1)** Using object names that contains spaces **(2)** Months names/abbrev for dates (actually avoid using anything else other than yyyy-MM-dd)

Comment: Yes, I used this as a quick example only . Actual feed is entirely different. Thankyou for sharing best practises along side:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All changes

```
datatable (["Column A"]:string, ["Column B"]:string, ["Modified at"]:string)
[
   ,"Row 1" ,"Value 1" ,"Dec 15"
   ,"Row 2" ,"Value 2" ,"Dec 15"
   ,"Row 3" ,"Value 6" ,"Dec 15"
   ,"Row 4" ,"Value 5" ,"Dec 15"
   ,"Row 1" ,"Value 1" ,"Dec 14"
   ,"Row 2" ,"Value 2" ,"Dec 14"
   ,"Row 3" ,"Value 6" ,"Dec 14"
   ,"Row 4" ,"Value 4" ,"Dec 14"
   ,"Row 1" ,"Value 1" ,"Dec 13"
   ,"Row 2" ,"Value 2" ,"Dec 13"
   ,"Row 3" ,"Value 3" ,"Dec 13"
   ,"Row 4" ,"Value 4" ,"Dec 13"
]
| partition hint.strategy=native by ['Column A']
  (
        order by ['Modified at'] asc
        | where ["Column B"] != prev (["Column B"]) and row_number() != 1
  )
```

| Column A | Column B | Modified at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 4 | Value 5 | Dec 15 |
| Row 3 | Value 6 | Dec 14 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WSwYrCMBRF94X%20w51s2oIItdHFgIuZcevGxWxKGVLzRgM1kZhaBD9%20WmVshUiTzeNyeBx4VwrX/rIixDn7MlV90PhgxfvJWaV3EzzCz6dwbaT6VSQh3CNPwiAPAwATtjENUtYO36Kq6T6uaIt0zgbErCdmfiLriYWf4D0x9xNeDz7qwUc9%20AsP7ie8HtmoR/bCI/MTXo%20OKMLgiqOwTjllNPZKu2l7N%20Fod1lq4dSZUF6QR/8liIpubXzbfXvGSrJ3ZnD%20qIA4bXvqimZPlp6Kg7cljpbOg461aQKhJaxpfnR9KMnGScel3arkD2VkQUeXAgAA)

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helps. What if we have multiple colums and not just one as in above example column B.

if there are multiple colums and there is not one fixed column where change is expected. can we iterate somehow to all colums of a particular partition and find out what has changed ?

Comment: Please post a new question with the relevant details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74847430/change-tracking-using-kusto-queries

Comment: Can you please explain the logic to put row_number() != 1 here ?

Comment: ok, I think I get that now. Partition defines each with a starting row number as 1 and the next partition again starts with row number 1 and not 4. So here are 4 partitions with 3 rows each starting with 1

Answer (score 0):

2 days diff

```
let t = datatable (["Column A"]:string, ["Column B"]:string, ["Modified at"]:string)
[
   ,"Row 1" ,"Value 1" ,"Dec 15"
   ,"Row 2" ,"Value 2" ,"Dec 15"
   ,"Row 3" ,"Value 6" ,"Dec 15"
   ,"Row 4" ,"Value 5" ,"Dec 15"
   ,"Row 1" ,"Value 1" ,"Dec 14"
   ,"Row 2" ,"Value 2" ,"Dec 14"
   ,"Row 3" ,"Value 6" ,"Dec 14"
   ,"Row 4" ,"Value 4" ,"Dec 14"
   ,"Row 1" ,"Value 1" ,"Dec 13"
   ,"Row 2" ,"Value 2" ,"Dec 13"
   ,"Row 3" ,"Value 3" ,"Dec 13"
   ,"Row 4" ,"Value 4" ,"Dec 13"
];
let 1st_day = "Dec 13";
let 2nd_day = "Dec 14";
t
| where ['Modified at'] in (1st_day, 2nd_day)
| summarize  arg_min(['Modified at'], old_val = ['Column B'])
            ,arg_max(['Modified at'], new_val = ['Column B']) by ['Column A']
| where old_val != new_val
| project-away ['Modified at*']
```

| Column A | old_val | new_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 3 | Value 3 | Value 6 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WSQU%20EMBCF7yT8h5FLwdQD0PWg2cOqVy8evJCGdLd1rSnFQBEx/nhhXeii3dBemnnf67xmqoQBA2vgzPR7qwSEWXBfqqbQsAnoTW0qqfcYpuLdrPhYcvkiBQdmpnrke5nvAQAOnsoW4qA/PDPViN/jg9hBvApOiMQSiZtILXHtJoglVm7CmYMs5iCLOciZHMRNOHOkiznSMzlSN%20HMMRD01vdUP/S4NjlnXT/6UTsKieYzgQyC8b1vaF9FJSBDJ0NHFKSG8HgZHs3RgNdNUbBKfgkAVu3zQurwjxdDqXj%20wVTfLEPjB0M0OjxkWvhgZ5//7Vq0LjtsO1vYIGrDj/0u1qN30N6r8k3szBVrWTd/3yWiP8yAZloiAwAA)

Comment: This also provides the changed but this would give change only between first modified and last modified times in row and would skip intermediate changes.

If the value changed from say:
Value 3 to value 6 and then again value 3 .
This logic will not return row 3.

I guess partioning basis rule name would work well

Comment: Didn't you say "I can run this query daily to find the daily change tracking"?

Comment: Agree, with daily execution this will also work as solution. Thanks for all your help