# Change tracking using Kusto queries

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, change-tracking

I have data in kusto table that gets updated with every deployment. I want to check what change was made in a particular deployment

[ColumnA  ColumnB   ColumnC ColumnD        Modifiedat
Row1    Value1        C6        D6             Dec15
Row2    Value2        C2        D2             Dec15
Row3    Value6        C3        D5             Dec15
Row4    Value4        C4        D4             Dec15
Row1    Value1        C1        D1             Dec14
Row2    Value2        C2        D2             Dec14
Row3    Value6        C3        D5             Dec14
Row4    Value4        C5        D4             Dec14
Row1    Value1        C1        D1             Dec13
Row2    Value2        C2        D2             Dec13
Row3    Value3        C3        D3             Dec13
Row4    Value4        C4        D4             Dec13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gscpO.png)

Now if we need to track change by column A values in column B Row 3 has a value change on Dec 14 load (From Value 3 to Value 6 ) Row 4 has a value change on Dec 15 load (From Value 4 to Value 5)

I want to extract data on each date as for what all has changed like to project only changed rows for a date ,and I can run this query daily to find the daily change tracking

[ColumnA          ColumnB   ColumnC  ColumnD    Modified at
Row3           Value6       C3       D6           Dec14
Row4           Value4       C5       D4           Dec14
Row2           Value2       C6       D7           Dec15
Row1           Value1       C6       D6           Dec15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWQ5H.png)

Comment: Tagging @David דודו Markovitz

Comment: Can you please post example data as text in the question and not as image? Have a look at other questions with the `kql` tag on how to post example data.  Otherwise it makes it very hard to draft example queries.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments it would help, if you post your datasets as a text.

If you would like to query the current data (with the latest modification), you could do this with the arg_max operator

```
datatable(Fruit: string, Value : int, timestamp : datetime ) [
    "Apple",  1, datetime(2022-01-01),
    "Banana", 2, datetime(2022-01-01),
    "Apple",  3, datetime(2022-01-03),
    "Banana", 6, datetime(2022-01-05)
]
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by Fruit
```